# Javafx event processing fails when Scene.depthBuffer is true

Tags: javafx

In javafx, when the Scene.depthBuffer is false 3D objects are distorted but a MeshView is able to receive mouse event.  When Scene.depthBuffer is true, 3D objects are displayed correctly but a MeshView will no longer receive mouse events.

Does anyone know why and how to work around this so objects are displayed correcty and mouse events are received?

[image: Display when depthBuffer is false.]
[image: Display when depthBuffer is true]

```
package us.bringardner.solid3d.ui;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.CullFace;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import us.bringardner.solid3d.api.ISolid;
import us.bringardner.solid3d.api.ISolidFactory;

public class TestFxPane extends Application {
private StackPane viewStackPane;
private FlowPane viewContainer;

private double anchorAngleX;
private double anchorAngleY;
private double anchorX;
private double anchorY;
private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
private final Rotate rotateZ = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);
private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
private BorderPane rootPane;
private Group viewGroup;

private MeshView getCsgCube() {
    int size = 100;
    ISolid csg = ISolidFactory.getFactory().Cube(size, false);
    csg = csg.movex(size);
    csg.setName("Cube");
    return csg.toJavaFXMesh();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}



@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    rootPane = new BorderPane();


    MeshView view = getCsgCube();
    view.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE));
    view.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
    view.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, (event)->{
        if(event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            //These events are not received when Scene.depthBuffer is true
            System.out.println("Mesh event="+event);
        }
    });

    viewGroup = new Group(view );
    viewContainer = new FlowPane(viewGroup);
    viewContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    viewContainer.setColumnHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
    viewGroup.getTransforms().addAll(rotateX,rotateY,rotateZ);
    viewContainer.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, (event)->{
        EventType<? extends MouseEvent> type = event.getEventType();
        if(type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            
            System.out.println("Pane event="+event);
            anchorX = event.getSceneX();
            anchorY = event.getSceneY();
        } else if( type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            if( event.isMiddleButtonDown()) {
                double deltax = event.getSceneX() - anchorX;
                double deltay = event.getSceneY() - anchorY;
                viewGroup.setTranslateX(deltax);
                viewGroup.setTranslateY(deltay);
            } else {
                rotateZ.setAngle(anchorAngleY - (anchorX - event.getSceneX()) );
                rotateX.setAngle(anchorAngleX - (anchorY - event.getSceneY()) );
            }
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    viewStackPane = new StackPane(viewContainer);                   
    rootPane.centerProperty().set(viewStackPane);
        //                                         |        set this to false and 3d objects are distorted but the MeshView does receive events.
        // --------------------------------------  V  ----  set this to true and 3d object display correctly but events are no longer received by the MeshView.
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 1000, 1000,true);
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
    scene.setCamera(camera);        
    stage.setScene(scene);
    
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I replaced your MeshView with a Box, and your issue appeared to replicate.

I replaced all of the 2D layout panes you are using with groups and translated so that the object still appeared in the center of the view, then mouse events seemed to work OK.

I think moral of the story is -> **don't use 2D layout panes in 3D scenes**, the results will be unpredictable.

Instead, just use groups and do your own layout logic in 3D.

For 3D work, I don't advise using the 2D layout system (the layoutX and layoutY properties of nodes) as it wasn't built for that. Instead, position using translation (translateX, translateY and translateZ properties of nodes).

Consider [3d picking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/picking.htm). If you need it, Oracle provides some sample code for picking 3D objects using a mouse, `PickMesh3D.java` in a zip file linked from the tutorial page I linked to here.

To debug mouse events on the scene, add this code to your example:

```
scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, System.out::println);
```

Sure, it will output a lot of spam, but it will also tell you what the target of the mouse events are (and it can be seen that the targets are the layout panes and not the object you wish to manipulate).

**Example Code**

When this code is run the Box will receive all mouse events directed at it.  I kept the variable names and debug lines the same even though they are no longer panes, so that you can more easily compare the code with your original.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.shape.CullFace;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestFxPane extends Application {
    private Group viewStackPane;
    private Group viewContainer;

    private double anchorAngleX;
    private double anchorAngleY;
    private double anchorX;
    private double anchorY;
    private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateZ = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    private Group rootPane;
    private Group viewGroup;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        rootPane = new Group();


        Box view = new Box(100, 100, 100);
        view.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE));
        view.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
        view.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, (event) -> {
            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                //These events are not received when Scene.depthBuffer is true
                System.out.println("Mesh event=" + event);
            }
        });

        viewGroup = new Group(view);
        viewContainer = new Group(viewGroup);
        viewGroup.getTransforms().addAll(rotateX, rotateY, rotateZ);
        viewContainer.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, (event) -> {
            EventType<? extends MouseEvent> type = event.getEventType();
            if (type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {

                System.out.println("Pane event=" + event);
                anchorX = event.getSceneX();
                anchorY = event.getSceneY();
            } else if (type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
                if (event.isMiddleButtonDown()) {
                    double deltax = event.getSceneX() - anchorX;
                    double deltay = event.getSceneY() - anchorY;
                    viewGroup.setTranslateX(deltax);
                    viewGroup.setTranslateY(deltay);
                } else {
                    rotateZ.setAngle(anchorAngleY - (anchorX - event.getSceneX()));
                    rotateX.setAngle(anchorAngleX - (anchorY - event.getSceneY()));
                }
//                event.consume();
            }
        });

        viewStackPane = new Group(viewContainer);
        viewContainer.setTranslateX(500);
        viewContainer.setTranslateY(500);
        rootPane.getChildren().add(viewStackPane);
        //                                         |        set this to false and 3d objects are distorted but the MeshView does receive events.
        // --------------------------------------  V  ----  set this to true and 3d object display correctly but events are no longer received by the MeshView.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 1000, 1000, true);

        //scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, System.out::println);

        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**Relevant code from the Oracle Picking example**

This code installs some mouse handlers on a 3d shape and, in each handler, gets the picking information for the associated mouse events. The picking information is reported into text fields.

Reported information includes:

- the node picked,
- the face of the node picked,
- the 2d texture coordinate picked,
- the 3d point picked,
- the distance of the picked point from the viewer.

From `PickMesh3D.java`

```
private void activateShape(final Shape3D shape, final String name) {

    shape.setId(name);

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> moveHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            PickResult res = event.getPickResult();
            setState(res);
            event.consume();
        }
    };

    shape.setOnMouseMoved(moveHandler);
    shape.setOnMouseDragOver(moveHandler);

    shape.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            PickResult res = event.getPickResult();
            if (res == null) {
                System.err.println("Mouse entered has not pickResult");
            }
            setState(res);
        }
    });

    shape.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            PickResult res = event.getPickResult();
            if (res == null) {
                System.err.println("Mouse exited has not pickResult");
            }
            setState(res);
            event.consume();
        }
    });
}

final void setState(PickResult result) {
    if (result.getIntersectedNode() == null) {
        data.setText("Scene\n\n"
                + point3DToString(result.getIntersectedPoint()) + "\n"
                + point2DToString(result.getIntersectedTexCoord()) + "\n"
                + result.getIntersectedFace() + "\n"
                + String.format("%.1f", result.getIntersectedDistance()));
    } else {
        data.setText(result.getIntersectedNode().getId() + "\n"
                + getCullFace(result.getIntersectedNode()) + "\n"
                + point3DToString(result.getIntersectedPoint()) + "\n"
                + point2DToString(result.getIntersectedTexCoord()) + "\n"
                + result.getIntersectedFace() + "\n"
                + String.format("%.1f", result.getIntersectedDistance()));
    }
}

/*
 * Copyright (c) 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 * This file is available and licensed under the following license:
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *  - Neither the name of Oracle nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *    from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
```

Comment: For posterity: If you need 2D controls in addition to the 3D nodes, then you can use a 3D `SubScene` for all the 3D stuff and embed that in any layout of the window's `Scene` (which would remain 2D).